# unwanted advertising tabs open in every 20 mins in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, virus, firefox-extensions

my usb stick was containing som kind of virus which was visible and my little brother double clicked on it! and now my laptop is infected!!
the virus opens several Firefox tabs and opens some websites as advertisement!
the virus does this every 20 minutes whether the browser is open or not!! and it is driving me crazy.
I dont know how to prevent it from opening tabs :(

---

I checked and there is no unwanted add-on or plugin on my browser! should I delete my browser?

Answer (score 0):

First, go into control panel and try to uninstall whatever programs you don't use or need or that may be a virus just in case you installed something bad.

Next, go to task manager and try to see any unusual or sketchy programs running and try to end the task.

Then, go to task manager startup tab and disable all unneeded processes on startup and see if the virus/program is there. If a sketchy program is on startup, try to uninstall it.

Also, if you haven't fixed the problem already, go to process explorer and wait for the virus/programs to open Firefox again. When it does, you might see it there and you can remove it.

Some viruses are stored in `%appdata%` of your computer and `%temp%`. Make sure you delete everything in `%temp%` and only delete things you really don't need in `%appdata%`.

If then you still haven't fixed your problem, install an anti-virus like [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/lp/sem/uk/?gclid=CjwKCAjw8J32BRBCEiwApQEKgYlG4v1zFs34r5R6Txd4soRqBsMPw1-Nuh5CWa6zBkj9yhubiIhLxBoCfYsQAvD_BwE) and get a free trial which might fix your problem.

I hope you manage to fix your problem, have a nice day :) Make sure you add this as the correct answer if I've solved your problem so you can help others too!